# Ternary operator multiple instructions per true/false

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

I have this code:

```
pin_number == pin ? @balance -= amount : puts pin_error
```

Additionally to the balance amount subtraction, I want to `puts` the new balance in the true section. How do I do that? If I try to make a new line, it seems to destroy the ternary operation.

Sometimes, the ternary operator doesn't work unless I put `puts` or something similar before the condition. The following:

```
condition ? puts "if_true" : puts "if_false"
```

doesn't work but:

```
puts condition = "if_true" : "if_false"
```

does work. Why is that?

Comment: _"doesn't work"_ – do you get an error or unexpected output?

Comment: Your sentence is total gibberish. I understand you are not a native English speaker, but I suspect it is not totally due to that. You probably can write more carefully.

Comment: What part is gibberish sawa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular `if/else` statement, it'd be much easier to read and maintain

```
if pin_number == pin
  @balance -= amount
  puts @balance
else
  puts pin_error
end
```

Now about your p.s. part

`puts` is regular method. It doesn't work in ternary because you've omitted parenthesis and ruby ruby can't parse this line correctly. This code will work

```
condition ? puts("if_true") : puts("if_false")
```

Comment: "Use regular `if/else` statement" – It's not a statement, it's an *expression*. That's important, because otherwise it would not be possible to replace the `?:` conditional operator with an `if`/`else` conditional expression. In C, for example, the conditional operator is *required*, because it is an expression and `if`/`else` is a statement, so you *cannot* use `if`/`else` if you need an expression. In Ruby, the conditional operator is just useless, it can always be trivially replaced with a conditional expression.